# Matrix clustering using Python

Tags: python, graph, cluster-analysis, networkx

I'm working on a growing matrix of data. I found that probably the best way to make my computations faster, I need to clusterize it somewhat in a way of this: [Clusterized matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZLyY.jpg)

My matrix shows connections between nodes on a graph with their weights on the intersections.
I made a graph using NetworkX and noticed it does something similar. Screenshot: [NX's Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibz2c.png)
Maybe I could use NetworkX's code to cluster it instead of growing my code by another function?

If not, then any python way of doing it would be helpful. I read many tutorial on hierarchical clustering but it all seems to be about connecting points in a two-dimensional space, not in the graph-space with given 'distances'.